# JPA / Hibernate : call stored procedure with input and output parameters

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a problem to call a sorted procedure in Java with JPA

**Here is the code Java :**

```
    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery = getEntityManager().createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("RECPOCH");

storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_PARAM_STRSTARTSIM, pochetteCriteria.getDebutNumPochette());
storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_PARAM_STRLASTSIM, pochetteCriteria.getFinNumPochette());
storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_PARAM_NACTELID, pochetteCriteria.getActelId());

storedProcedureQuery.execute();
Integer result = (Integer) storedProcedureQuery.getOutputParameterValue(Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_PARAM_NRESULT);

return Long.valueOf(result);
```

**Here is the code Oracle :**

```
"RECPOCH" ( NACTELID IN NUMBER, STRSTARTSIM IN VARCHAR, STRLASTSIM IN VARCHAR, NRESULT OUT INTEGER )
```

**Trace Exception :**
`13:24:40.295 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
Hibernate: {call RECPOCH(?,?,?,?)}
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:230)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:223)
    ... 90 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Le nombre de noms de paramètre ne concorde pas avec celui des paramètres inscrits
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.setNamedParameters(OracleSql.java:198)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:197)
13:24:40.833 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:197)
13:24:40.833 [http-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@6db6eb5c]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement.execute(HikariProxyCallableStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.(OutputsImpl.java:52)
    ... 95 more`

**Named Sorted procedure definition in entity :** 
    `@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
            @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_NAME, procedureName = "RECPOCH", parameters = {
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(name = Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_PARAM_NRESULT, mode = ParameterMode.OUT, type = Long.class),
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(name = Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_PARAM_STRSTARTSIM, mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class),
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(name = Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_PARAM_STRLASTSIM, mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class),
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(name = Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_PARAM_NACTELID, mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Long.class)
            })
    })`
Do you have an idea, please ?

Comment: Where is the definition of named stored proc `RECPOCH` ? As per http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/query.html#stored_procedures_named

Comment: I added definition in my question, I defined it in entity Class

Comment: perhaps put the parameters in the same order in the NamedStoredProcedureQuery as in the actual stored proc? Ought to not matter ...

Comment: Yes, i kept the same order in NamedStoredProcedureQuery  like oracle declaration

Answer (score 0):

You also need to register the parameters for the stored procedure, so your code would look like:

```
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery = getEntityManager().createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("RECPOCH");

storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter(Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_PARAM_STRSTARTSIM, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_PARAM_STRSTARTSIM, pochetteCriteria.getDebutNumPochette());

storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter(Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_PARAM_STRLASTSIM, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_PARAM_STRLASTSIM, pochetteCriteria.getFinNumPochette());

storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter(Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_PARAM_NACTELID, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedureQuery.setParameter(Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_PARAM_NACTELID, pochetteCriteria.getActelId());

storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter(Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_PARAM_NRESULT, Integer.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

storedProcedureQuery.execute();

Integer result = (Integer) storedProcedureQuery.getOutputParameterValue(Pochette.SP_RECPOCH_PARAM_NRESULT);

return Long.valueOf(result);
```

EDIT: This does not help for the question of the OP, since `createNamedStoredProcedureQuery` is used, which automatically declares and registers the parameters. I'll leave it here for completeness.

Comment: True, except he (allegedly) has a **named** stored procedure query, so that would be done automatically when he defined his "named" query

Comment: Ah sorry, did not see that part. I will edit my post :)

Comment: does not work, i have the same error, i forgot to say that I declared the namedSortedProcedure  in the entity width parameters